# How to check if an FB AppRequest has been clicked on or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api, curl, facebook-app-requests

One can get his app's AppRequests using FB Graph. How can I get if the receiver clicked on any of the AppRequests?

Edit: I can't pass additional parameters in the AppRequest, it's an "AppInvite" and through AppLinks the receiver is taken to the Apple's AppStore etc and no info lives on after the download.

My use case is when two current users invite the *same* "new user". The "new user" clicks in only *one* of the invites, of course, but I can't figure out which one it is right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per FB's Graph API there isn't a way to identify which AppRequest were clicked or not. I can get the list of all AppRequests from my app **but** there isn't a boolean field indicating which one has or hasn't been clicked on.

[Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-request)

Answer (score 5):

As per [facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/app-request) you can pass an arbitrary data parameter to be used for tracking purposes. You could pass a unique id that you keep a reference to the from->to relationship in your db to know which invite was invoked.

edit: let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Not very helpful. I use AppInvites which takes the "clicker" to Apple's AppStore directly and I can't pass any "additional" data along the AppInvite. If I *can* and just don't know how please let me know...